# Why does SecureRandom.uuid create a unique string?

Tags: ruby

Why does `SecureRandom.uuid` create a unique string?

```
SecureRandom.uuid
# => "35cb4e30-54e1-49f9-b5ce-4134799eb2c0"
```

The string that method `SecureRandom.uuid` creates is never repeated?

Answer (score 17):

The string is not in fact *guaranteed* unique. There is a very small but finite chance of a collision.

However in practice you will never see two ids generated using this mechanism that are the same, because the probability is so low.

You may safely treat a call to `SecureRandom.uuid` as generating a globally unique string in code that needs to manage many billions of database entities.

[Here is a small table of collision probabilities.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)

Opinion: If I were to pick an arbitrary limit where you *might* start to see one or two collisions across the entire dataset with a realistic probability I would go for around `10**16` - assuming you create a million ids per second in your system, then it would take 30 years to reach that size. Even then, the probability of seeing any collisions over the whole 30 years of the project, would be roughly 1 in 100000.

Comment: What is the basis for `10**16`?

Comment: @sawa: I'm checking my facts right now, but it is roughy `0.01 * Math.sqrt(2**122)` - the square root is important, look up "the birthday paradox"

Comment: Thanks for the information, but converting the probability of collision (which is rather easily achieved) to the expected (average) number of trials until collision is not trivial.

Comment: @sawa: It's not too bad. I'm pretty comfortable with quoting 1 in 100000 probability for a database with 10**16 records. That's not the same at all as saying I expect to see a collision. Instead it is precautionary. I've marked that part as *opinion* just to make it clear it's not as factual.