# Creating unique token for URL's Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, time, uniqueidentifier

I am using ahoy emails gem for emails analytics. For tracking the emails they are just

```
@ahoy_message = AhoyEmail.message_model.new
ahoy_message.token = generate_token
```

The generate token method is like,

```
   def generate_token
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(32).gsub(/[\-_]/, "").first(32)
   end
```

I suspect that there may be duplication in the generated tokens, I can check whether the generated token is unique each time, So I am trying to change the token generation method like below,

```
 def generate_token
   URI.escape(Base64.encode64 "#{Time.now.to_f},#{@mail.id}") # @mail is object in db
 end
```

Is the default method fine else can I use something related to time to create unique tokens?

Comment: Personally, I would use [`SecureRandom.uuid`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#uuid-method) because it's already there as part of  standard library. However, just like any "unique-generation" (non-transactional, and non-retryable) algorithm, it's still subject to race condition. See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090424/why-does-securerandom-uuid-create-a-unique-string) for insights.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/23/has-secure-token-to-generate-unique-random-token-in-rails-5.html

You can use `has_secure_token` to automatically generate token for an attribute of a model.